# TP-LINK WN722N Wireless USB device recognized as Ethernet device by macOS

Tags: macos, driver, kernel-extension

I am developing a kernel extension (`kext`) for `TP-WN722N-v1` because it is not supported. 
I managed to upload the firmware to the device, it is recognized by the system and, aparently, it is working with veeery basic support.
I can find it under Networks in Settings panel, but it is recognized as an `ethernet device`, so I can not use it yet.
Where should I start to make the system view it as a `wireless interface`? Did I inherited from the proper class?

My class start like this:

```
class TL_WN722N : public IOEthernetController
```

Comment: Update: I added the fact that USB network driver kexts are deprecated to the answer. You may want to use DriverKit instead of implementing a kext.

Comment: I was just reading about this yesterday, I think I will be moving soon to DriverKit, but I am focusing in making it work first. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple's own Wifi drivers are based on the `IO80211Controller` class, which is a subclass of `IOEthernetController`.

[image: Screenshot of AppleBCMWLANCore node in IORegistryExplorer.app]

Unfortunately, this isn't a public KPI. There was at one point a "leaked" header file, and there have been some efforts to reverse engineer it by the Hackintosh crowd. I don't know if anyone has actually got a driver working based on that.

Any manufacturer-provided 3rd party wifi drivers I've seen have skipped `IO80211Controller` and simply subclassed `IOEthernetController` directly, (re-)implementing any wifi-specific stuff directly in the driver. Any UI for selecting the SSID etc. will need to go through a custom App and can't use Apple's own wifi UI in the Network preference pane or in the menu bar icon. This is likely to be quite a lot of work, but it's definitely possible.

Note that implementing USB network device drivers in kexts is *deprecated* as of macOS 10.15 Catalina, and any such kext will likely stop working in 10.16. You should be using DriverKit for targeting future versions of macOS.

Comment: It's USB *Ethernet* device kext driver is deprecated. There is no support for 80211 device driver support in DriverKit yet as of macOS 11.

Comment: @WeiShen There was never any direct support for 802.11 devices in `IONetworkingFamily`. As I said in my answer, all working 3rd party wifi drivers I've seen subclass `IOEthernetController` as `IO80211Controller` is private. If [NetworkingDriverKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkingdriverkit) isn't good enough for your purposes, I strongly recommend getting in touch with Apple directly to discuss the recommended course of action. I do **not** advise waiting around for DriverKit to gain native 802.11 support because there is a good chance it will never come.

Comment: @WeiShen The macOS 11 beta which was released last week already refuses to load USB network adapter kexts. If you are responsible for a network driver kext, you need to port it to DriverKit *now* or users who upgrade to macOS 11 when it's released in (probably) late 2020 will no longer be able to load your driver.